# Navigating to another view controller without a navigation controller

Tags: iphone, view

As you guess am still a newbie, getting my head around iphone development.
I am just trying out basic view loading on demand, which i cant get to work

I have an app, with 2 view controllers, each view controller connected a different nib file.
I am trying to switch between view manually; there is no navigation control involved.

How can i manually push the second view to the first view?
`self.navigationController pushViewController` wont work since there is no navigation controller.
How else can I push the second view on top of the first view and destroy the first view; and ofcourse vice versa?
I have done this in the first view's button action:

```
SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sv animated:YES];
```

obviously, it didn't work.

`window addSubView` didn't work either, because the first view controller is the root view controller (not sure i said that right). In other words, when i run the app, the first view is what I see with a button that is supposed to load the second view.

I have spent hours searching for a simple example, and I couldn't find any.

Any suggestions?

Comment: SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
 [self.view addSubview:sv.view];
 [sv release]; THe seem to have worked, but with no animation; how can i add the animation just like it happens with the navigation controller

Comment: edited my answer. :) to include animation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in the first view controller you need this:

```
- (IBAction)pushWithoutViewController:(id)selector {
    NextNavigationController *page = [[NextNavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:NextNavigationController bundle:nil];
    CGRect theFrame = page.view.frame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
    page.view.frame = theFrame;
    theFrame.origin = CGPointMake(0,0);
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8f];
    page.view.frame = theFrame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view addSubview:page.view];
    [page release];
}
```

and then link it to the button in nib. :)

Comment: Great, Gyani & thomas, your solutions work!  Gyani's solution only gives one animation, sliding it up, is there any option in the presentModalViewController where i can set the animation from right to left?  Thomas solution is much more elaborate and i can control the animation whichever way and speed i want.

Comment: this solution only replaces the view, instead of view controller. also, initWithNibName accepts first argument as NSString, instead of class. Therefore, it should be written as... initWithNibName:@"NextNavigationController"...

Comment: Ah well spotted on the initWithNibName front... forgot my @""... :p You don't ever "replace" a view controller. Its only an object. All you're doing is owning the object instead of giving it to the navigation controller to control.

Answer (score 9):

try :

```
SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sv animated:YES];
```

Comment: hi gyani, is it possible to add a different kind of animation with that same statement?

Comment: @Veeru Yes it is possible to add different kind  of animation 
e.g
SecondView *sv=[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
sv.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:sv animated:YES];

Comment: Thanks a bunch gyani and thomas as well. I am giong with gyani's method as it involves less code. THanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

IF you have first xib and you want to give navigation to another controller then you have to declare navigation in to `appdelegate.m`
write following code to app

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = navController;
```

then in ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)NextButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    yourNextViewController *objyourNextViewController = [[yourNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"yourNextViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:objStartUpViewController animated:TRUE];
}
```