# TTThumbsViewController

Tags: iphone, three20

Is it possible to add a TTThumbsViewController sub class on a UIView without uising TWNavigationController

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is use a portion of the TT framework, without using all of it... I'd consider one of the other thumbnail view controllers available. I like https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser and https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer

Comment: Hello Kenny, Thanks for the replay. Actually what I am trying to do is, add a TTHumbsViewCOntroller in a UIView like [someView addSubView:ThumbsViewInstance.view]. In many examples, the ThumbsViewController is added to the Navigation controller and displayed as modal view complete with the done button on the navigation bar etc. I actually dont want it to be displayed like that. I just want it as a simple view. Any suggestions? I'll check whatever you suggested. Thanks again

Comment: so you're trying to present a view controller without using a navigation controller? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132209/iphone-programming-navigating-to-another-view-controller-without-a-navigation-c

Comment: you can also just hide the navigation bar, while still using the navigation controller

Comment: Or, are you trying to add a TThumbsViewController as a subview of some other view controller? if this is the case, i'd try subclassing TThumbsViewController with your other view controller.

Comment: subclassing will let do a thumbs view and whatever your enclosing view was supposed to do, in one controller. Apple suggests one view controller on screen at one time, I believe.

Comment: did u found the solution? I am stuck! Please help